# Why is ComboBox SelectedIndexChanged being called before form load?

Tags: vb.net, combobox

why **Private Sub combobox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles combobox.SelectedIndexChanged** called before form appears?
In my understanding, this function should be called **ONLY** when user change the selected index of mycombobox? Am I wrong?

How to stop it from running automatically?

Comment: The `SelectedIndexChanged` event also occurs when the selected index is changed programmatically.

Comment: what do you mean by the selected index is changed programmatically? I cannot understand...

Comment: It means when the combo box selection is changed via code.  In your case, it is probably happening when the combo box list items are populated or when the initial selection is set.

Comment: how to stop it? Or use other events?

Comment: @BAE you should use the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event. This fires only when the user selects an option

Comment: @Jaxedin I hope the function to be triggered when selected index is changed too.

Comment: @BAE you always can invoke IndexChanged programmatically on ChangeCommited if you need

Comment: @Jaxedin Thanks I hope the function to be triggered when selected index is changed by my code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use a Boolean flag indicating when it is "safe" to handle the event, or you could use the alternative syntax to add your event handler AFTER the Form is loaded and all the initialization has been done.

For this you use the `AddHandler` syntax:

```
AddHandler combobox.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf combobox_SelectedIndexChanged
```

Hope this helps

EDIT:

Using the `AddHandler` syntax, you must make sure NOT to add the `Handles` clause to your event handler declaration:

```
Private Sub combobox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
'you event handler code
End Sub
```

Then, typically at the end of the Form's `OnLoad` override, you'll use the `AddHandler`:

```
Public Class Form1

    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)

        ' Initialization code/whatever

        AddHandler ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf combobox_SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub combobox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'Your event handler code
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I think event handlers **ONLY** can be added automatically. How can I stop them to be added automatically and then I add them in form loading function?

Comment: Simply don't add the `Handles combobox.SelectedIndexChanged` clause in your handler declaration.

Comment: If needed, you can even use `RemoveHandler` to remove the event handler. This gives you fine control over when a handler should be (or not) called. You can add and remove them dynamically in your code as needed.

Comment: @LucMorin another option instead of a flag or messing with handlers is to use [**SelectionChangeCommited Event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted.aspx) as this event is only raised when a user changes the selecteditem.

Comment: @Codexer maybe, but my solution also applies to other Controls who might  raise events at a time when everything is not properly initialized (CheckBox for example). Adding and removing handlers dynamically is not "messing" with them. I see it rather as controlling when the event should start/stop being handled.

Comment: A good solution like any other, but have to recognize that @Codexer have mentioned the best approach, and, in my oppinion, dynamically adding/removing event handlers should be considered only for objects that are dynamicaly created, otherwise, it is a starting point to produce some kind of spaguetti code, then I consider it a bad practice (because not really required to dinamycally associate event-handlers instead of using the **Handles** clause, in this scenario).

Comment: Try SelectionChangeCommitted. The SelectionChangeCommitted event is raised only when the user changes the combo box selection, and you can create a handler for this event to provide special handling for the ComboBox when the user changes the selected item in the list. Alternatively, you may either make sure the form is already loaded, or parse the sender.

Comment: I don't know how it came up on my page.

Comment: You must have been doing a search and hit the sort button to go from oldest to newest 
 :-)